# How to make Adobe Flash work on every webbrowser

Tags: flash, adobe

I am working with Adobe Flash on a site
[www.stayac.se](http://www.stayac.se)

Adobe Flash player does not working in Edge i was allowed forced to make Adobe Flash to work!

But i want it to work on every web Browser?

Can i add something in the index.html file to make it work automatically without allowing stuff?

Comment: Why not just recreate the slideshow in Javascript? It's a 1 day task and the result will work even on mobile browsers.

Comment: Is it better than webgl?

Comment: WebGL is a part of JavaScript. All I was suggesting is that you recreate the fade in/out effects using Javascript code for the animation. You could also try recording the animation with a screen recorder and then just use the output video on your page. Code option is better cos you can change pictures or customize the effects/speed. The record-as-video option is easier but not flexible to future changes (any new text or images),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: no, you can’t make Flash Player work automatically in every browser.

Depending on the browser and OS of your visitor, they might not have Flash installed or enabled. Even if they do, the browser might still be set up to ask for permission to run on each new web page. For example, it seems like Google Chrome blocks Flash automatically for every web page, unless you manually unblock it:

> If you quit Chrome, your Flash settings won’t be saved. The next time you open Chrome, you’ll have to allow Flash again for any sites you added before.

Additionally, Microsoft plans on [removing Adobe Flash Player from Microsoft Edge by the end of 2020](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/04/update-adobe-flash-end-support/). This is also the case for all other major browsers, as [Adobe will end the support after December 31, 2020](https://www.adobe.com/nl/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html). So even if there were an option, it would probably stop working, soon.

Depending on your needs, it might be worth looking into using HTML5, WebGL and WebAssembly to replace the functionalities of your Flash Player app.